# Cannot select columns by their names in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I downloaded a [PostreSQL file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lerocha/chinook-database/master/ChinookDatabase/DataSources/Chinook_PostgreSql.sql) that creates and populates the *Chinoook* database (a relatively well known database used for testing).

I then opened the file on [sqliteonline](https://sqliteonline.com/) (an online compiler where you can test SQL code).

Opening the SQL file created and populated all tables as expected. However, the following query throws an error:

```sql
SELECT ArtistId
FROM "Artist";
```

> db error: ERROR: column "artistid" does not exist

Which is odd, because the column does exist in that table:

```sql
select *
from "Artist";
```

| ArtistId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AC/DC |
| 2 | Accept |
| 3 | Aerosmith |
| 4 | Alanis Morissette |
| 5 | Alice in Chains |

How come I cannot select any columns by their names?

Comment: I'd try `"ArtistId"`.